# Live tiles with 5 images in cycle

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, live-tile

I know how to show a simple `Live Tile` in a `Windows Store App`. I used to charge an XmlTemplate string choosing certain width.

But, I've seen that there some apps that show like 5 different live tiles. By example, `Photos` app show 5 images in cycle and change each 5 seconds so so.

How can I perform this functionality in my app or if you can show an app demo from Windows 8.1 samples, I would be greatful with you.

Comment: Any problems with answers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a [msdn sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/app-tiles-and-badges-sample-5fc49148). But it's a bit cryptic for my taste.

In simple steps, you should create 5 tiles (or less) and put them into notification queue. Enable queue and supply tileTagId.

Here is my code: 
AllTiles - array with all the tiles. `AppTileId` - secondary tile Id. You can change it to the primary tile by uncommenting the line with `CreateTileUpdaterForApplication` code.

```
// Posting update
int tileTagId = 0;
foreach ( XmlDocument XmlTile in AllTiles )
{
    TileNotification tileNotification = new TileNotification( XmlTile );
    tileNotification.Tag = tileTagId.ToString();
    TileUpdater secondaryTileUpdater = TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForSecondaryTile( AppTileId );
    //TileUpdater secondaryTileUpdater = TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication();
    secondaryTileUpdater.EnableNotificationQueue( true );
    secondaryTileUpdater.Update( tileNotification );
    tileTagId++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should enable the [notification queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781199.aspx).